# How to reverse a multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to reverse a 2d array that was made with pointer notation.

To be clear, if the array is

```
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
```

I need:

```
E D C B A
J I H G F
O N M L K
```

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEIGHT 3
#define WIDHT 7

void print (char *imprimir)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDHT;j++)
        {
            printf ("%2c",*(imprimir+(i*WIDHT)+j));
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    //FILLING THE ARRAY
    char *array=malloc(WIDHT*HEIGHT);
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDHT;j++)
        {
            *(array+(i*WIDHT)+j)=(i*WIDHT)+j+'a';
        }
    }
    print (array);  
    //TRYING TO REVERSE IT
    char *tmp=malloc(WIDHT);
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDHT/2;j++);
        {
            *tmp=*(array+(i*WIDHT)+j);
            *(array+(i*WIDHT)+j)=*(array+(i*WIDHT)+(WIDHT-j));
            *(array+(i*WIDHT)+(WIDHT-j))=*tmp;
        }
    }
    printf ("PRINTING RESULT!\n");
    print (array);  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two errors.

1. You have a semicolon `;` at the end of the your inner for loop, so the loop is not running at all.
2. Wherever you have `WIDTH - j`, you should instead have `WIDTH - 1 -j`, because the highest index is `WIDTH - 1`.

Additionally, humans do care about spelling, so I changed `WIDHT` to `WIDTH` globally to improve readability.

Here is the fixed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEIGHT 3
#define WIDTH 7

void print (char *imprimir)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            printf ("%2c",*(imprimir+(i*WIDTH)+j));
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

}



int main ()
{
    //FILLING THE ARRAY
    char *array=malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT);
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDTH;j++)
        {
            *(array+(i*WIDTH)+j)=(i*WIDTH)+j+'a';
        }
    }
    print (array);  
    //TRYING TO REVERSE IT
    char tmp;
    for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<WIDTH/2;j++)
        {
            tmp=*(array+(i*WIDTH)+j);
            *(array+(i*WIDTH)+j)=*(array+(i*WIDTH)+(WIDTH - 1 -j));
            *(array+(i*WIDTH)+(WIDTH - 1 -j))=tmp;
        }
    }
    printf ("PRINTING RESULT!\n");
    print (array);  

}
```

Comment: thanks!! so many time just for that silly mistake... I really aprecciate your help, and I am sorry My range don't allow me to vote up your answer. thank you

Comment: @sirpsychosexy, That is a hard mistake to spot. I recently had a one character error myself (with an extra `&`) so I know how you feel.

Answer (score 1):

At least the error in the string `for (j=0;j<WIDHT/2;j++);` because you don't want to have an empty cycle there, right?
Here is your code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define HEIGHT 3
    #define WIDHT 7

    void print (char *imprimir)
    {
        int i,j;
          for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<WIDHT;j++)
            {
                printf ("%2c",*(imprimir+(i*WIDHT)+j));
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }

    }



    int main ()
    {
        //FILLING THE ARRAY
        char *array=malloc(WIDHT*HEIGHT);
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<WIDHT;j++)
            {
                *(array+(i*WIDHT)+j)= (i*WIDHT)+j+'a';
            }
        }
        print (array);  
        //TRYING TO REVERSE IT
        char *tmp=malloc(WIDHT);
        for (i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<WIDHT/2;j++)
            {
                *tmp=*(array+(i*WIDHT)+j);
                *(array+(i*WIDHT)+j)=*(array+(i*WIDHT)+(WIDHT-j-1));
                *(array+(i*WIDHT)+(WIDHT-j-1))=*tmp;
            }
        }
        printf ("PRINTING RESULT!\n");
        print (array);  

}
```

Comment: I've found the second error and here is my working code for you.